# Seeing both Google tag manager and Google analytics tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Hi I am learning google tag manager and started using tag assistant extension in chrome. In the tag assistant extension I am seeing both tags google analytics bar (with analytics ID) and google tag manager bar (with gtm ID). Is it normal? Like google assistant extension should show both of them? Also there is a specific warning "Same web property ID is tracked twice", is that due to extra tags (meaning unnecessary tags implemented by mistake)?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check you site code and verify there is not olg GA code there so you can get rid of the warning.

Ones you do this you should still see Google Analytics being loaded on Tag Assistant cause under the hood GTM loads GA.

If you want you can provide me with the site URL and i can check if something is wrong.
Hope it helps!